# android: spinner - set position of selected item to bottom

Tags: android, dialog, position, spinner

i have a spinner-dialog.

when i open it, i want to see my selection on bottom.

> how can i set the position from my pre selected spinner-item to bottom?

per default (when opening it is on top):

[image: per standard]

.

> my wish (when opening it should be on bottom like this):

[image: my wish]

Comment: nobody, has an idea, to solve this "simple" thing? (i can't find a solution) :/

Comment: noone, has an idea? :(